AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided when within an ADF pipeline
I've got an issue in Azure Data Factory while fetching an access token from the Microsoft Graph API. Some of my client secrets return an "invalid_client" error in ADF, yet all of them work perfectly in Postman.
The client secret values are correct (not the IDs).
No typos or extra spaces in the client secret.
Using secure strings in ADF for storing the client secrets.
Client secrets are not expired.
I've re-validated and re-entered credentials in ADF (credentials being fetched from key vault via web activity, used as input parameter to separate authentication pipeline)
I've also compared request details between ADF and Postman to ensure they are identical.
Is there a known issue with ADF handling client secrets, or am I missing something in the configuration? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Error: invalid_client,
Error Description:AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is the client secret value, not the client secret ID, for a secret added to app 'appID'
